# Undoing an edit by someone else

Tags: support, editing

My question has been [edited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/469375/revisions) by a >2k-rep user in a way which makes it oddly formatted (code-quoting of brand names) and grammatically incorrect. Is there a way to undo the edit, apart from just making a further edit to correct it?

Sorry for the basic question. I am a fairly experienced user on StackOverflow, but things work a bit differently as a 405-rep beginner!

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469811/ .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can roll back to a previous version. Click "edited ... (timestamp)" under the post, and then "rollback" next to the version you want.